# How to make Variables under Settings an Environment variable in Robot Framework

Tags: python, pycharm, robotframework

I am implementing Robot Framework for one of the products, where i have come across a file config.yaml to read all the credentials used to login to DB servers. I want to know how to make Variables under settings section an Environment variable and pass the file from command line.

```
*** Settings ***

Library         RequestsLibrary
Library         Collections
Library         JSONLibrary
Library         OperatingSystem

Variables       ../../Config.yaml
```

I expect ../../Config.yaml to be declared as Environment Variable and Pass it through command line . i.e

```
robot testfile.robot <path>/Config.yaml
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can try 
**`robot --variable path_config:somewhere testfile.robot`** to create variable
and in your import

```
*** Settings ***

Library         RequestsLibrary
Library         Collections
Library         JSONLibrary
Library         OperatingSystem

Variables       ${path_config}/Config.yaml
```